# Camera move in and out

Tags: camera

With the reference image im tracing an image. And when im in camera view i can see the image and my model perfect. When i just pan and it out from the camera view im much far from the model. Always i have to click the <kbd>.</kbd> key and come near and when i have to go in camera view it right direction but when out from the camera view same im away from the mesh. My camera is set to orthographic view.

[image]

Any suggestion why im always away from the model and not the same distance when press <kbd>.</kbd> key.

Comment: you need **press 0 (Cero)** in your numeric keyboard **to enter or exit** the camera

Comment: The default behavior when exiting camera view with Numpad 0 is to restore the previous view position. If you middle click in camera view, that should exit camera view without actually altering the view angle. Just be careful not to drag; lifting the mouse when clicking can help avoid that.

Comment: That said, you can use background images outside of camera view, in case that helps. Set the *axis* for the given background image in the `N` region. Image empties might also be useful.